# Do my "dal" and "fileHandler" interfaces overlap?

Tags: java, interfaces, persistence, google-guice

I want my program to:

1. read some input lines from CSV file
2. write the output lines to plain string file
3. read some input from the same file in (2) 
   and compare it to some calculated data

I want to consider these abstraction levels:

- create `Dal` interface with CRUD operations
- implement `Dal<T1>`, `Dal<T2>`, `Dal<T3>`
- create FileHandler interface with `read` and `save` operations
- implement `CsvFileHandler`, `StringFileHandler`

And then:

- `Dal<T1>` will implement `read` with a member of `CsvFileHandler`
- `Dal<T2>` will implement `read` and `write` with a member of `StringFileHandler`
- `Dal<T3>` will implement `write` with a member of `StringFileHandler`

Is it OK that `Dal<T1>` and `Dal<T3>` really implement `Dal` only partially (not all CRUD). Or should I choose other abstractions?

I'm using guice DI and I need to differentiate `Dal<T1>` and `Dal<T2>` even though they both `read` / `write` type `String`. So I created a dummy different classes for `T1`, `T2`.

Do you think I use too much abstraction? Are `FileHandler` and `Dal` overlapping?

Any other way to differentiate Guice injection rather than create `dummyTypes`?

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) you should not have implementations which do not fully implement an interface.

I rather have two or three different interfaces which state exactly what they can. Maybe a class will at the end implement more than one interface...

The other benefit you gain is that when you have specific interfaces they do not need to be further qualified in order for Guice to know which instance you need. If you still have more than one implementation of an interface you can use annotation to qualify them. See [Binding Annotations](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations)